# basic probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Hi guys im wondering is this the relationship between the cdf and pdf?

If $\xi \sim (0,1)$ and $\Phi$ denotes the CDF and $\phi$ denotes the standard normal density function does $\xi \Phi[x]= \phi[x]$ ?

Comment: For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\mathbb{P}(\xi = \phi(x)/\Phi(x))=0$, so no it doesn't hold.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\xi \sim (0,1)$?